# Search using UITexfield

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to ask. how can i search an array of string I map from an object than I want search it from uitextfield, I try this method but it didn't work. where do I do wrong? here this is my code setup.

```
var cities = [City]()
var cityNames = [String]()

    private func populateCities() {
        BasicInfoServices.shared.getCity { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let cities):
                self?.cities = cities
                let names = cities.compactMap { $0.name }
                self?.cityNames = names
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cityNames.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CitiesAlertCell.cellId, for: indexPath) as! CitiesAlertCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        let item = cityNames[indexPath.row]
        cell.item = item
        return cell
    }

    func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        searchTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        cityNames.removeAll()
        return true
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if searchTextField.text?.count != nil {
            self.cityNames.removeAll()
            for str in cityNames {
                let range = str.lowercased().range(of: textField.text!, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil)
                if range != nil {
                    cityNames.append(str)
                }
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
        return true
    }
```

Comment: `cityNames.removeAll` followed by iterating of the array doesn't make sense.  Instead, keep a "master" list which you then generate a "filtered" list from.

Comment: You should take one other array for "filteredData" and this array will load in tabelView when you search otherwise, you load your main cityNames array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, removing the clutter, you are essentially doing this...

```
self.cityNames.removeAll()
for str in cityNames {
    //...
    cityNames.append(str)
}
```

You remove all the elements from the array and the try to iterate over it, but since there is, now, nothing in the array, there is nothing to iterate over.

You could use a "filtered" array, which takes it's input from the a "master" array.  The "filtered" array is what would be displayed to the user

```
var filteredCities: [String]()

private func populateCities() {
    BasicInfoServices.shared.getCity { [weak self] result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let cities):
            self?.cities = cities
            let names = cities.compactMap { $0.name }
            self?.cityNames = names
            self?.filteredCities = names
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when you need to filter the list...

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if searchTextField.text?.count != nil {
        self.filteredCities.removeAll()
        for str in cityNames {
            let range = str.lowercased().range(of: textField.text!, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil)
            if range != nil {
                filteredCities.append(str)
            }
        }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
    return true
}
```

This of course will mean you will need to use `filteredCities` instead of `cityNames` in your table data source ;)

Having said all that.  I'd consider doing something slightly differently.  Instead of using master/filter lists, simply use the `cities` array as the master and filter it directly...

```
if let text = searchTextField.text, !text.isEmpty else { 
    cityNames = cities.filter { $0.name.lowercased().range(of: text, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil }.map { $0.name }
} else {
    cityNames = cities.map { $0.name }
}
```

If speed is an issue, you could fall back to the master/filtered list of `String` values, which would allow you to remove the need to `map` the results, but at this point, I'd be questioning why you'd need a `String` list anyway

## For example...

```
var cities = [City]() // Master
var cityFilter = [City]() // Filter

private func populateCities() {
    BasicInfoServices.shared.getCity { [weak self] result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let cities):
            self?.cities = cities
            self?.cityFilter = cities
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cityFilter.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CitiesAlertCell.cellId, for: indexPath) as! CitiesAlertCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    let item = cityFilter[indexPath.row]
    cell.item = item // The item is now a city reference
    return cell
}

func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    searchTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    cityFilter = cities
    return true
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if let text = searchTextField.text, !text.isEmpty else { 
        cityFilter = cities.filter { $0.name.lowercased().range(of: text, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil }
    } else {
        cityFilter = cities
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
    return true
}
```

If you're worried about cities with `nil` names, then I'd `filter` the original list, so that the master list only contained valid values

Answer (score 1):

In your `textFieldShouldReturn` method you are removing all names and then iterating.As a result there will be no results .You must use another array to hold search results.

```
var filteredCityNames = [String]()

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        filteredCityNames = []
        if searchTextField.text?.count != nil {
            for str in cityNames {
                let range = str.lowercased().range(of: textField.text!, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil)
                if range != nil {
                    filteredCityNames.append(str)
                }
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
        return true
    }
```

You can use this `filteredCityNames` for that

Comment: I try to use filteredCityNames.count in tableView numberOfRow, since when I see your code the filteredCityNames not being in use in TextFieldShouldReturn. and it didn't work @ManuRaphy

Comment: You can simply filter your modal array

let filteredArray = cities.filter{ ($0. name.contains(“TextInYourTextField”)) }